# Solving: $\frac{3x-1}{2} =\frac{-2}{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve :
$$\frac{3x-1}{2} =\frac{-2}{x+2} $$

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $2(x+2)$ to begin with.

Comment: And remember, that $x\neq-2$, just in case. It will have no incidence here, but that's always safer to keep track of the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{3x-1}{2} =\frac{-2}{x+2} $$
$$(x+2)(3x-1)=2\cdot(-2) $$
$$3x^2+5x+2=0$$
$$a=3,b=5,c=2$$
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Sadly, it s possible, certainly in North America, that the OP has not been exposed to the Quadratic Formula. That way, one can keep on asking factorization questions. The quadratic $3x^2+5x+2$ factors nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-multiply, and solve the resulting quadratic in $x$. Don't forget to check your solutions in the original equation (though it isn't going to be a problem this time).